# HTML- CSS: Center social media icons text

Tags: html, css, icons

I have the following social media menu that is part of my navigation top bar menu. My problem is that it doesn't display the social media text in center.

[image]

CSS

```
 .fa {
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 47px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  left: auto;
  border-radius: 70%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#tpbr_box .a {
    width: 10%;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 20px!important;
}
#tpbr_box .social2{
    float:right;
}

#tpbr_box  {
        font-size: 20px!important;
}
.top_nav{
      display: flex;
}
.top_nav    .social2  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
}
.info{
      margin: 0 auto;
}
.social2 a{ padding-left: 4px; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="top_nav">
    <div class="info">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i> |
     <a style="color:white;" href="tel:2434">tel 3242342</a> |
 
    </div>
     <div class="social2">
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Why the social media letters are not in center? what is wrong?

Comment: I could not recreate the problem, could you provide the full HTML and CSS for the containers that you're wrapping the fa icons in?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AMR you are right. Just uploaded full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line right here:

```
.social2 a{ padding-left: 4px; }
```

Comment that out and they'll be centered.